# Regex in Java where text on which search is being done is dynamically changing

Tags: java, regex

In Java, find()+start()+end() can be used for extracting regex pattern which occur more than one time using there functions on `matcher` object.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); 
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()){ 
   String subString = text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
   text = text+subString; 
}
```

In my case text is changing with every find() in while loop so next time matcher.start() and matcher.end() gives wrong indices. I mean these indices are correct for old text but as text is changing it gives incorrect indices.
(Here text is changing next time start() and end() function return indices which are not expected).

Comment: Your Question is not clear.. please add more information..

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);                                     
 Matcher matcher = p.matcher(text);
 while(matcher.find()){
     String subString = text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
     text = text+subString;                                     
 } 

 Here text is changing next time start() and end() function return indices which are not expected. Is it clear from the code above ?

Comment: The indices returned by a Matcher apply only to the value of `text` when you called `p.matcher(text)`.  Any changes you make to `text` after calling `p.matcher(text)` are not seen by the Matcher at all.  If `text` changes, you must create a new Matcher or call reset(text) on the existing Matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @VGR mentioned, an instance of `Matcher` will only search on the string it was originally given.  If you want to search on a new string, then you must create a new instance of `Matcher`.  In your case, your next search would then start at the index after the last match.  For example:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
int start = 0;
while (matcher.find(start)) {
    text = text + text.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    start = matcher.end();
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
}
```

If you're not already aware, then you should know that `text = text + subString` creates an entirely new `String` object, which is then assigned to the original `text` variable.  This means that although `text` references the "updated" text, `matcher` only knows about the `String` object that `text` referenced when you created `matcher`.  This is why for your use case, you must create a new instance of `Matcher` every loop.

---

Alternatively, you might consider using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in order to avoid the overhead of creating an entirely new string (and matcher) every iteration.  You would still have to track the `start` index though, since you would need to reset the `Matcher` object every iteration in order for it to recognize the updated / longer internal end index (i.e. appended text) of the `StringBuilder` object.  For example:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(text);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringBuilder);
int start = 0;
while (matcher.find(start)) {
    stringBuilder.append(stringBuilder, matcher.start(), matcher.end());
    start = matcher.end();
    matcher.reset();
}
text = stringBuilder.toString();
```

---

Finally, do be careful.  Unless you have some really funky mojo going on in that regex (which would be another problem entirely), then this code will loop forever if it finds at least one instance of the pattern in the text.  I suggest you put an additional condition or some sort of counter on the `while` loop.

Comment: thanks a lot Travis, thats the exactly my problem. I have tried reset() also but sometimes it resulted into infinite loop I got the issue. Iam doing similar to the code you given. I have also used appendReplacement() function.

Comment: @AnujPandey What exactly are you trying to do?  If this is your actual code (with no other conditions in the loop), then I think your problem might be at the design level rather than the code level.  This code should never be executed as-is precisely because of the danger of an infinite loop.  I only provided it as a direct answer to your question